# Add request header to pass the authentication on websocket sampler

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, stomp

How do I add request headers to pass authentication through websocket sample in JMeter? I don't see the option to add request headers on websocket open connection sampler. And does this sampler support STOMP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) features

> integrates with JMeter's Header Manager to set additional HTTP headers on WebScoket upgrade request

so it's sufficient to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and put your header(s) there - the sampler will pick them up.

Particularly this sampler doesn't support STOMP per se, you might want to assess the [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Text_Oriented_Messaging_Protocol#Implementations) and choose the one which your system under test expects

Comment: Is there a custom WebSocket sampler available that supports STOMP?

Comment: This guy does: https://github.com/Fyro-Ing/JMeter-WebSocket-StompSampler